# Prove that the set of permutations of a finite non-empty set is a group with respect to the composition of functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, solution-verification

So, the question is in the title but i'll just repeat it formally as follows:

Let $X$ be a non-empty, finite set. Then, $P(X)$ is the set of permutations of $X$. The pair $(P(x),\circ)$, where $\circ$ denotes the composition of functions, is a group.

Honestly, I think I have this down because this is literally just an exercise in verifying that the axioms of a group hold for this particular pair. However, I just want someone to see if the structure of my proof/my wording is okay or not.

---

Proof Attempt:

First, we prove closure. Let $f \in P(X)$ and $g \in P(X)$. They are invertible functions so we have to prove that $f \circ g$ is invertible as well. We just have to show that $f \circ g$ is bijective.

$(f \circ g)(x_1) = (f \circ g)(x_2) \implies f(g(x_1)) = f(g(x_2)) \implies g(x_1) = g(x_2) \implies x_1 = x_2$

That proves injectivity. To prove surjectivity, consider the following:

$(f \circ g)(X) = f(g(X)) = f(X) = X$

Hence, $f \circ g$ is bijective and, therefore, is invertible. So $f \circ g \in P(X)$.

Secondly, we prove associativity. Let $f,g,h \in P(X)$. Then:

$((f \circ g) \circ h)(x) = (f \circ g)(h(x)) = f(g(h(x))) = f((g \circ h)(x)) = (f \circ (g \circ h))(x)$

Which holds for all $x \in X$.

Thirdly, we need to show the existence of an identity element. Let $I: X \to X$ be our choice of an identity element. To show that it actually is an identity:

$(f \circ I)(x) = f(I(x)) = f(x) = I(f(x)) = (I \circ f)(x)$

Finally, we need to show the existence of inverse elements. Let $f \in P(X)$. Since f is invertible, $f^{-1}$ is invertible and belongs to P(X). This shows the existence of inverses.

Since the pair clearly satisfies all the axioms of a group, it is a group.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: Oof thank you so much!

Comment: It may be worth noting that in proving associativity you didn't use the hypothesis that $f,g,h$ are *bijections on $X$*, but just *maps from $X$ to $X$*. Even more generally, associativity holds for any maps $h\colon A \to B, g\colon B \to C, f\colon C \to D$, where $A,B,C,D$ are generic sets.

Comment: Oh nice, nice. That's actually pretty cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proof is entirely correct. In fact, your proof never used that $X$ is finite. Thus your proof also shows that the permutations of an infinite set $X$ form a group, which is correct! You did more than you had to prove!

For extra information, a common notation to denote the permutation on a set $X$ is $\operatorname{Sym}(X)= \{f: X \to X: f \mathrm{\ bijective \ map}\}$.

If $X= \{1, \dots, n\}$, we write $S_n$ instead.

If you haven't encountered this notation before, you will probably soon see it in a group theory course.

Comment: Oh nice, that's interesting. Unfortunately, i won't see it unless I'm gonna study group theory at some point. I'm self-studying all of this stuff while waiting to enter university.

Comment: I must say I'm impressed by your skills if you are still in high school!

Comment: Nope. I graduated in 2017 and had to serve in the military for 2 years. I did quite a bit of competition math & physics but got tired of the fact that it wasn't really all that rigorous. So, I've actually just been focusing on learning things super rigorously and writing proofs.

Comment: If you really want full rigour, maybe a university (pure) math degree is just the thing for you.

Comment: Yeap I'll be attending university this year to do pure mathematics (hopefully).

Comment: Good luck. I feel like you have the right mentality to bring that to a good end!

Comment: Thank you so much. It's nice to hear that, considering that it's tough to know when you're doing things wrong/right when self-studying a subject.

Comment: Self studying is always hard. One hint I can give to pick the books: never pick a book that's too difficult, but start with an easy one, then a somewhat harder one and then the hard one. This will take less time than starting with the hard one. What topics are you self-studying? From what I see, group theory and linear algebra?

Comment: At the moment, I'm trying to work through 4 textbooks on my own: Fundamentals of Mathematics by Bernd Schroder, Modern Calculus with Analytic Geometry by Richard Silverman, Algebra & Geometry by Alan Beardon and Linear Algebra by Klaus Janich. I quite like all of them and they certainly fit my style of presentation. I've been working through them extremely slowly though, because I've basically been filling in all the blanks that the authors have left in. So, all theorems and examples that they don't prove, I tend to prove in my notes.

Comment: I mean, I don't mind it taking a while. I'd rather focus on getting a good understanding of the material than rush through the proofs of theorems and such. Actually, most of the time, the author presents a theorem and a full proof but i cover that up & try to prove the theorem on my own first. More recently, i've been trying to pre-empt a possible discussion that the author is going to go into after making some definition or proving some result.